# QSvgRenderer painting problems

Tags: qt, svg

I am trying to render a subclassed QGraphicsObject, called Part, to a QGraphicsScene.

```
class Part : public QGraphicsObject {
    Q_OBJECT;
public:
    Part(std::map<std::string, std::string> data, QString part_svg_file);
    void setSharedRenderer(QSvgRenderer *r);
    void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget);
    QRectF boundingRect() const;

    QGraphicsSvgItem* GetPartSvg();
    QGraphicsSvgItem* GetTerminalsSvg();
private:
    QGraphicsSvgItem *m_part_graphic;
    QGraphicsSvgItem *m_terminal_graphic;
    QSvgRenderer *m_svg_renderer;
    QDialog *m_dialog;
    std::map<std::string, std::string> m_data;

}; // class Part
```

This part contains two QGraphicsSvgItems. These two items are generated from the same SVG file upon construction of Part:

```
Part::Part(std::map<std::string, std::string> data, QString part_svg_file) 
    : m_terminal_graphic(new QGraphicsSvgItem(part_svg_file)),
      m_part_graphic(new QGraphicsSvgItem(part_svg_file)),
      m_svg_renderer(new QSvgRenderer())
{
    m_part_graphic->setElementId("part");
    m_terminal_graphic->setElementId("terminals");
}
```

There are two items as the SVG contains two groups, one called "part" and the other called "terminals"

I want these two items to be rendered to the QGraphicsScene, I have them in seperate QGraphicsSvgItems to allow me to turn the "terminals" group off in certain instances.

I though the proper way to do this was to render them in the paint event of my parent QGraphicsObject class. However, this is not working.

```
void Part::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option, QWidget *widget) {
    painter->setPen(Qt::PenStyle::SolidLine);
    painter->setPen(Qt::black);
    painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
    painter->setBrush(Qt::black);
    painter->drawRect(0, 0, 25, 25);
    m_part_graphic->setSharedRenderer(m_svg_renderer);
    m_svg_renderer->render(painter);
}
```

I am drawing a simple rectangle to ensure that the paint event is getting called properly. The rectangle is being drawn on the scene in the appropriate place. The QGraphicsSvgItem, m_part_graphic, is not being drawn on the scene. What is the proper way to do this?

To recap, I want to draw two different QGraphicsSvgItems onto a QGraphicsScene as part of a larger class called "Part".

---

**UPDATE**

At the suggestion below, I started a new project and began with a basic graphicsview render of an SVG.

```
m_svg_item = new QGraphicsSvgItem("C:\\Code\\QT_Testing\\QT_Testing\\Resources\\bubbles.svg");
m_svg_item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsToShape);
m_svg_item->setZValue(0);

s->addItem(m_svg_item);
```

If I remove the `s->addItem(m_svg_item);` line, it compiles and runs fine. Obviously doesn't draw the SVG at that point either.

It is crashing and giving me the follwing: (MS Visual Studio Pro 2012)

Output Window:

> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to
>   objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 3f0730. Receiver
>   '' (of type 'QGraphicsSvgItem') was created in thread 3ff0a0", file
>   kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 535 Debug Error!
>
> Program: C:\QT\4.8.5\bin\QtCored4.dll Module: 4.8.5 File:
>   global\qglobal.cpp Line: 2303
>
> ASSERT failure in QCoreApplication::sendEvent: "Cannot send events to
>   objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 3f0730. Receiver
>   '' (of type 'QGraphicsSvgItem') was created in thread 3ff0a0", file
>   kernel\qcoreapplication.cpp, line 535

And the Call Stack:

```
msvcr110d.dll!_CrtIsValidHeapPointer(const void * pUserData=0x004a76b0) Line 2036   C++
msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg_nolock(void * pUserData=0x004a76b0, int nBlockUse=0) Line 1322  C++
msvcr110d.dll!_free_dbg(void * pUserData=0x004a76b0, int nBlockUse=0) Line 1265 C++
msvcr110d.dll!operator delete(void * pUserData=0x004a76b0) Line 54  C++
QtGuid4.dll!QGradientBrushData::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)  C++
QtGuid4.dll!QBrushDataPointerDeleter::deleteData(QBrushData * d=0x004a76b0) Line 247    C++
QtGuid4.dll!QBrushDataPointerDeleter::cleanup(QBrushData * d=0x004a76b0) Line 257   C++
QtGuid4.dll!QScopedPointer<QBrushData,QBrushDataPointerDeleter>::reset(QBrushData * other=0x00432f38) Line 149  C++
QtGuid4.dll!QBrush::operator=(const QBrush & b={...}) Line 636  C++
```

---

main.cpp:

```
#include "qt_testing.h"
#include <QtGui/QApplication>


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QT_Testing w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

qt_testing.cpp:

```
#include "qt_testing.h"
#include "svgview.h"

#include <QtGui>

QT_Testing::QT_Testing(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent),
      m_view(new SvgView)
{
    setCentralWidget(m_view);
    setWindowTitle("SVG Viewer");
}

QT_Testing::~QT_Testing()
{

}

void QT_Testing::openFile(const QString &path) {
    QString file_name;

}

void QT_Testing::setRenderer(QAction *action) {

}
```

svgview.cpp:

```
#include "svgview.h"

#include <qfile.h>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtSvg\qgraphicssvgitem.h>

SvgView::SvgView(QWidget *parent)
    : QGraphicsView(parent)
    , m_renderer(Native)
    , m_svg_item(0)
    , m_background_item(0)
    , m_outline_item(0)
{
    setScene(new QGraphicsScene(this));
    setTransformationAnchor(AnchorUnderMouse);
    setDragMode(ScrollHandDrag);
    setViewportUpdateMode(FullViewportUpdate);

    QPixmap tile_pixmap(64, 64);
    tile_pixmap.fill(Qt::white);
    QPainter tile_painter(&tile_pixmap);
    QColor color(220, 220, 220);
    tile_painter.fillRect(0, 0, 32, 32, color);
    tile_painter.fillRect(32, 32, 32,32, color);
    tile_painter.end();

    setBackgroundBrush(tile_pixmap);

    QGraphicsScene *s = scene();

    s->clear();
    resetTransform();

    m_svg_item = new QGraphicsSvgItem("C:\\Code\\QT_Testing\\QT_Testing\\Resources\\bubbles.svg");
    m_svg_item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemClipsToShape);
    m_svg_item->setCacheMode(QGraphicsItem::NoCache);
    m_svg_item->setZValue(0);

    /*m_background_item = new QGraphicsRectItem(QRect(0, 0, 300, 300));
    m_background_item->setBrush(Qt::white);
    m_background_item->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
    m_background_item->setVisible(true);
    m_background_item->setZValue(-1);*/

    //s->addItem(m_background_item);
    s->addItem(m_svg_item);

    s->addEllipse(150, 150, 100, 100, QPen(Qt::black, Qt::PenStyle::SolidLine));

    s->setSceneRect(-10, -10, 320, 320);
}

void SvgView::drawBackground(QPainter *p, const QRectF &) {
    p->save();
    p->resetTransform();
    p->drawTiledPixmap(viewport()->rect(), backgroundBrush().texture());
    p->restore();


}

void SvgView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event) {
    QGraphicsView::paintEvent(event);
}

void SvgView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent *event) {
    qreal factor = qPow(1.2, event->delta() / 240.0);
    scale(factor, factor);
    event->accept();
}
```

Comment: The subitems are presumably children of your item and paint themselves. You don't need to do anything special to paint them at all - just ensure that they are, in fact, your item's children.

Comment: I changed my constructor initializer list to:
: m_terminal_graphic(new QGraphicsSvgItem(part_svg_file, this)),
      m_part_graphic(new QGraphicsSvgItem(part_svg_file, this)),

Comment: Now the program crashes with a "_BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Comment: This is infuriating. No matter how i try to draw an svg item using the QGraphicsSvgItem class, it crashes. I tried just generating the svgitem in the graphicscene constructor and adding it to the scene. that also crashes.

Comment: following this tutorial: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/painting-svgviewer-svgview-cpp.html, I also get the crash. Looking specifically at the openFile function.

Comment: Just put those things into a [stand-alone, minimal, compileable example](http://www.sscce.org). Just one `main.cpp` file, one `QGraphicsSvgItem` on a scene, ideally with the SVG file included in-line in the code (see `QBuffer`!). If it crashes, it's a Qt bug, and you've got a testcase ready to submit to the bugtracker. If it works, then you'll have a much easier job of figuring where your code is broken.

Comment: If it works, and I presume it would, slowly start morphing it into your full-blown code. Eventually it will break, and you'll know exactly why it broke. I hope you're doing all your tests under version control, like you should, and you commit ideally after each change (think dozens of commits per day).

Comment: Well, bad news. It does not work on a very basic example. I'm getting the same error. :/

Comment: I feel like this must be a problem with my environment. I basically followed the SVG view example minus a bunch of the extra  menu stuff and it crashes with the same error.

Comment: You absolutely, positively need to show a complete, single file example. The assert fires because it seems that things are created in different threads. You show a little snippet. We need the whole thing, including the `main()` function, the place where you instantiate the scene, literally - the whole thing.

Comment: The shown call stack is seemingly not from when the assert had fired, or is from the wrong thread. Run this using a debug build of Qt, under the debugger, it should trip when the assert fires, and make sure that you pick out the thread where `QCoreApplication::sendEvent` is on the stack.

Comment: Never mind that I don't see how you can get *two* asserts in a row. The first one would terminate the application. It seems to me that you're running things in two threads at once. I don't buy that this is with a stock Qt example, or without tweaks to the Qt sources, or something else that messes stuff up. Are you sure your system isn't "owned" by malware? Something might be injecting threads into all processes on your system.

Comment: It is stock QT. I am not spawing other threads or anything like that. I'll post the whole thing.

Comment: What exact Qt version is it, and what exact platform (OS/distro version, bitness, compiler version) and what is the source of the build (qt-project.org, self compiled, distro...)?

Comment: QT 4.8.5; Microsoft Visual Studio 2012; Window 7 64bit. QT was compiled from source under MSVC2012 (11). It all seemed to compile properly. The one thing I did have to do that was weird was install the QT 5 VS2012 add in as there is not one for 4.8.5. I'm very tempted to wipe my QT clean and build the 5.2 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As much as I hate this answer, here is what I did to fix this. Since QT 4.8.5 is not officially supported in Visual Studio 2012, I wiped my QT install completely and installed QT 5.2.1. After fixing a few include paths, the above code compiled and ran just fine. The SVGs are now drawing as expected. Thank you Kuba Ober for your help. It is much appreciated.